# Response time graph in New Relic with percentiles

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I have a requirement to reproduce an existing performance report as a New Relic graph. The existing report produced by our custom APM solution shows a graph with the average response time of all web requests in a given time period. Also plotted on the same graph are the 5%-95% and 1%-99% percentiles for the corresponding average response at the same time of week over the last 60 days. You select the time period start and end you are interested in.

I'm quite new to NRQL. Anyone know what query to use in New Relic to produce the same graph.

Thanks

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the chart types in APM is the percentile line graph accessed via a % button on the Response Time chart on the APM Summary page. That chart displays the Average, Median, 95th, and 99th percentiles. You can click the context menu (…) on that chart and select ‘View query’ which allows you to view the NRQL used to create that chart and would allow to adjust the NRQL for the specific percentiles that you are interested in. Percentile calculations require event data which may only be retained for 8 days in your account if using the default retention settings. The average is stored as a Metric and would be available for 13 months by default. You can view the NRQL used to select the Metric average by viewing the query on the default Response Time chart. https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apm-ui-pages/monitoring/response-time-chart-types-apm-browser/#percent